# Can't get total size of a bucket with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm trying to get the total size of a bucket. However total_size returns 0. Of course there are a couple of files in the bucket. If I have five files in my bucket the following function prints five zeros. What am I doing wrong?

```
bucket = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(signature_version="s3", s3={'addressing_style': 'path'})).Bucket(name)
for object in bucket.objects.all():
    total_size += object.size
    print(object.size)
```

Answer (score 11):

I see few issues:

- Not sure about your call to `boto3.resource()`. Is that correct?
- `total_size` not initialized

Try this:

```
total_size = 0
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('mybucket')
for object in bucket.objects.all():
  total_size += object.size
  print(object.size)
print(total_size)
```

Or a one liner:

```
sum([object.size for object in boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('mybucket').objects.all()])
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this:

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region,
                            aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                            aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
response = s3client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
bucket_size = sum(obj['Size'] for obj in response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change signature_version="s3" to signature_version="s3v4".

I also like helloV's answer.

Also specify the region for the bucket instead of relying on the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the size in GB:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bytes = sum([object.size for object in s3.Bucket('myBucket').objects.all()])
print(f'total bucket size: {bytes//1000/1024/1024} GB')
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python function which returns the bucket size using a daily metric stored in cloudwatch:

```
def get_bucket_size(bucket_name: str, region: str):
    cloudwatch = boto3.client("cloudwatch", region_name=region)
    result = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace="AWS/S3",
        Dimensions=[{"Name": "BucketName", "Value": bucket_name},
                    {"Name": "StorageType", "Value": "StandardStorage"}],
        MetricName="BucketSizeBytes",
        StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(2),
        EndTime=datetime.now(),
        Period=86400,
        Statistics=['Average'],
    )
    return result["Datapoints"][0]["Average"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to dump a list of objects on a daily basis, then calculate the totals from that.

Comment: But how do you do that with boto3?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, similar to @Rohit G's except it accounts for `list_objects` being deprecated in preference for `list_objects_v2` and that `list_objects_v2` returns a max of 1000 keys (this is the same behavior as `list_objects`, so @Rohit G's solution, if used, should be updated to consider this - [source](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects)).

I also included logic for specifying a prefix should anyone want to get just the size of a particular prefix in the bucket, but using as written will get the size of the entire bucket:

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket= 'myBucket'
prefix = ''
resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
total_size = sum([obj.get('Size') for obj in resp.get('Contents')])
while resp.get('NextContinuationToken'):
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, ContinuationToken=resp.get('NextContinuationToken'))
    total_size += sum([obj.get('Size') for obj in resp.get('Contents')])
print(f"Size (bytes): {total_size}")
```